# ¿Hay alguna manera de evitar que tomen captura de pantalla o screenshot a una aplicacion web?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en la que se mostraran algunos platillos de comida y sus recetas, solo que me están pidiendo que no se puedan tomar capturas de pantalla con la pc y tampoco con el celular o tablet ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo? Buscando un poco encontre un script algo viejo pero ya no funciona.

Comment: Nop. En pc tendrías que instalar una aplicación que corriese como servicio para evitarlo. En el celular se podría si fuese una aplicación, no estoy muy seguro de que se pueda controlar en el navegador del dispositivo.

Comment: y si tengo otro cel a mano y le saco desde otro cel?

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios me sirven de mucho.

Comment: Y si tuve en cuenta esa opcion @gbianchi pero aunque eso le explique al cliente aun asi quiere evitar los SS, de cualquier manera gracias por sus comentarios

Comment: En PC ni te molestes en buscar algo ya que tomar screens es una función del OS y el navegador funciona casi independiente al sistema y mucho más si es Chrome o Firefox. Incluso navegadores como Firefox incorporan sus propias funciones para capturar recortes de pantalla, más complicada la cosa.

Comment: la respuesta en esos casos al cliente es no se puede, demostrarselo, y si insiste, dejarlo libre... no se puede luchar contra eso, ni hacer algo que a la larga este mal, no funcione, y despues recibas los coletazos de eso que parece funcionar pero no funciona....

Comment: Hace tiempo que existen las *marcas de agua*. Toda captura o descarga de la imagen tendrá una marca de agua que indicará que la misma pertenece a un tercero. Para mi gusto no es nada estético, pero es una opción. Coméntala con tu cliente como una opción para proteger el contenido. Saludos

Comment: Explícale al cliente que no tiene sentido censurar una captura de pantalla de un sitio web puesto que no estás mostrando datos privados que pretendas ocultar, para eso están las páginas de administración. Tendría sentido si el sitio web es de streaming, como es el caso de Netflix, usado contra la piratería por contenido DRM, pero en tu caso lo veo chungo.

Answer (score 1):

Hasta lo que yo sé, no es posible controlar esa opción del Screenshot. Al menos para la versión web en PC. Solo puedes bloquear el clic derecho mediante un script, pero quien se la sabe de todas a todas, le basta con echarle ojo al código fuente de tu página y buscar lo que desea.

Para dispositivos móviles he visto que en algunas aplicaciones no puedes hacer screenshot. Un ejemplo de ello es en los chats secretos de Telegram o en los perfiles de Facebook Parejas.

Lo que podrías hacer es que, si las imágenes son propiedad de tu cliente, las registren bajo derechos de autor o en su caso ponerles una marca de agua.

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones es mejor no responderlas pues terminan cerradas

Comment: @BetaM ¿Y eso qué tiene que ver?

Comment: Es solo una observación y consejo para ti. Saludos